# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Doesn't Start Listening

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that connected to firebase. I want to fill recyclerview with my data from firebase. Before that I made an app and it was working fine. Now I am using same method and I am getting this error when I say adapter.startListening()

```
adapter.startListening()
```

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Numeric value out of
>   32-bit integer range: 1.561575795649E12. Did you mean to use a long or
>   double instead of an int?

Comment: In your Data model class make sure the variable is of type long/double instead of int

Comment: Thank you so much. Lesson learned: "Work with strings on firebase"

Answer (score 1):

The datatype in your Firebase Database is conflicting with that in your data class. Change it to the mentioned type, `long` or `double` instead of `int`.

Have a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for a comprehensive understanding on reading and writing data.